# Цикл проверки наличия данных в БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Такой вопрос: Можно ли сделать цикл проверки наличия данных в БД с помощью цикла if-else
Идея вот в чем, у меня стоят самописные новости, мне нужно чтобы бд выводило изображение только тогда когда оно есть, то есть, не выводило рамку при отсуствии источника (у меня просто стоят определенные ширина и высота)

Comment: можно. делайте.

Comment: а в чем проблема собственно ?

Comment: В базе есть источники изображений, в блоке новостей я сделал так что изображение имеет определённую высоту и ширину. Проблема в том, что когда нету ссылки на изображение, показывается рамка, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при отсуствии источника изображения в БД, не появлялся тег <img>

Comment: покажите html код блока новостей

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `title`, `content`, `image`, `date` FROM `red_news`", $link);
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo '<h2 style="border: 2px solid #bbb; border-radius: 5%;">'.$result['title'].'</h2><br> <img src="'.$result['image'].'" style="width: 560px; height: 360px; border: 1px solid #404040; border-radius: 2%;"><br><div class="paragraphe" style="border: 1px solid #404040;width: 560;"><p1>'.$result['content'].'</p1></div><br><em style="color: #bbb; font-family: sans-serif; ">Опубликовано: '.$result['date'].'</em>';
    }

Comment: В вопрос добавьте в нормальном виде :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, content, image, date FROM red_news", $link);

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { 
    $image = !empty($result['image']) ? '<img src="'.$result['image'].'" style="width: 560px; height: 360px; border: 1px solid #404040; border-radius: 2%;">' : '';

    echo '<h2 style="border: 2px solid #bbb; border-radius: 5%;">'.$result['title'].'</h2><br>'.$image.'<br><div class="paragraphe" style="border: 1px solid #404040;width: 560;"><p1>'.$result['content'].'</p1></div><br><em style="color: #bbb; font-family: sans-serif; ">Опубликовано: '.$result['date'].'</em>'; }
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало.